# HTML space before ul list

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get rid of the space between the last words "trading desks" and the first bullet point "With a background in Production Support". Yes i know there is a break tag there - however even when the break tag is not there, the space remains. For some reason without the break tag, the span tag will not italicize.

```css
#title span {
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
ul.bullet {
    list-style-type: disc;
}
ul.subbullet {
    list-style-type: circle;
}
span.bold {
    font-weight: bold;
}
span.italic {
    font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<p><span class="bold">UBS</span> 1285 Ave of Americas New York, New York 10006 07/14 - 05/16
    <br />
    <span class="bold">Trade Support Specialist</span><span class="italic"> Front office trade support for Cash Equities and Option trading desks.</span>
    <br />
    <ul>
        <li> With a backgournd in Production Support and experience in Linux System Engineering, provide comprehensive Front Line Application support to Floor Traders.</li>
        <li> Responsible for the maintenance, monitoring and permissioning of Order Entry, Vol discovery, Quoting and Hedging Applications. Provide Application Support for Middle Office jBoss and Tomcat Position Keeping Applicatons. Provide Applicaiton Support
            for clearing applications which rely on Oracle and Sybase Databases </li>
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't fully understand but, just a guess, why don't you try to add "display:block;" to that span and add "margin-bottom:10px;" or whatever value you want.

Comment: Your markup and CSS are both incomplete, which makes this difficult.  However, if I had to guess I'd say you're just fighting against browser styles automatically applied to the `ul` element (Chrome gives it a top and bottom margin, for example).  Try using a [CSS Reset](http://cssreset.com/what-is-a-css-reset/) as the first CSS applied and I imagine it will resolve this issue (although you may have other items you find you then have to re-style)

Comment: ... side note - `ul` cannot be nested inside `p`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `margin:auto` on your `p` and `ul` tags (However I do recommend adding ids to these specific tags and styling)

css rule

```
ul,p{
margin:auto;
}
```

**Snippet below without the break tag and margin:auto rule**

```css
#title span {
font-size: 1.2em;
}
ul.bullet {
list-style-type: disc;}
}
ul.subbullet{
list-style-type: circle;
}
span.bold {
font-weight: bold;
}
span.italic {
font-style: italic ;
}
li:first:child{
padding:0px;
}
ul,p{
margin:auto;
}
</style>
```

```html
<p> <span class="bold">UBS</span> 1285 Ave of Americas New York, New York 10006                                                07/14 - 05/16<br />
<span class="bold">Trade Support Specialist</span><span class="italic"> Front office trade support for Cash Equities and Option trading desks.</span>
<ul>
<li>    With a backgournd in Production Support and experience in Linux System Engineering, provide comprehensive Front Line Application support to Floor Traders.</li>
<li>    Responsible for the maintenance, monitoring and permissioning of Order Entry, Vol discovery, Quoting and Hedging Applications. Provide Application Support for Middle Office jBoss and Tomcat Position Keeping Applicatons. Provide Applicaiton Support for clearing applications which rely on Oracle and Sybase Databases </li>
```

Comment: p + ul {
    margin-top: -10px;
} I am playing with this - however the auto looks nicer thank you

Comment: this will only target all ul tags placed that p tags...both p tags and ul tags will need that margin:auto rule to achieved that best fit in this case